# Scrape link from element that has no class or id - casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am currently trying to scrape video links from this [SITE](http://www.pcmag.com/video/latest). The links are inside a carousel slider. The `a` tags don’t have a class or id therefore I am not sure how to target so casperjs can retrieve the `href` attribute. How could I scrape the links without class or id attributes?

HTML

```
<ul class="videos" >
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.test.com/article2/0,2817,2471677,00.asp">
            <img src="http://assets1.ignimgs.com/thumbs/compact.jpg">
            <span class="video-title">
                <div> Fujitsu ScanSnap iX100 </div>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var urls = ['http://www.test.com/'];
var casper = require('casper').create({});

function linkScraper(x) {
    var page_links = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { // start for loop
        current_page = x[i];
        casper.thenOpen(x[i], function() {
            casper.then(function() {
                this.getElementsInfo('a').forEach(function(element) {
                    // skip elements that don't have a href attribute...
                    if (!element.attributes.href) {
                        return;
                    }
                    //page_links
                    page_links.push(element["attributes"]["href"]);
                });
            });
        });
    }
    return {
        pl: page_links,
    };
}

//Crawl
function stringifyResult(webpages) {
    // here linksObj contains empty lists
    var linksObj = linkScraper.call(this, webpages);
    this.then( function() {
        var data = JSON.stringify( linksObj.pl );
        this.echo(data.length + ' links found.');
    });
}

casper.start().then(function() {
    this.echo("Fetching........");
});
casper.run( stringifyResult.call(casper, urls) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all desired links by a `ul.videos li a` *CSS selector*:

```
function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.videos li a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}
```

Complete working example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({}),
    links;

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.videos li a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

casper.start('http://www.pcmag.com/video/latest');

casper.then(function() {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Output:

```
173 links found:
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2470070,00.asp
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2470084,00.asp
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2470087,00.asp
...
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2475543,00.asp
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2475409,00.asp
 - http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2475359,00.asp
```

---

How to get the `span` texts example:

```
function getSpanTexts() {
    var texts = document.querySelectorAll('ul.videos li span.video-title');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(texts, function(e) {
        return e.textContent;
    });
}
```

Comment: is there away to store results in array like `[ 'link' : 'www.example.com']`?

Comment: @MaryCoding okay, make sure you are getting the `src` attribute value.

Comment: Sorry to bug one last thing: every`a` has an  `<span class="video-title"><div> Fujitsu ScanSnap iX100 </div></span>`, how would it be possible to retrieve the text?

Comment: @MaryCoding sure, please see the last code snippet.

Comment: @MaryCoding I've seen the topic you've mentioned here, but cannot find it anymore. Have you removed the question? Hope, at least, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution (I don't know Casper) but the idea is to replace

```
this.getElementsInfo('a')
```

With actually getting the `ul` itself with class `videos`. Then you will have to do logic to navigate into the `li`'s, then the `a`'s and pull out the links. I.e., don't scrape links; scrape the list elements you're interested in and can identify by class, then pull the link elements out of those.